# Constant paint rasterization in React

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, slowdown

While developing my React.js (v16.11) app I noticed a drop in page performance, so I went to chrome dev-tools to see what's happening. In Performance tab I noticed that I have four Rasterizer Threads constantly calculating something.

Tired of debugging, I finally created a fresh react project with `npx create-react-app my_app` and only changed `App.js` so that it prints `<h1>` element into the view:

```js
// src/App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Test</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I noticed that the same thing happened - I have a **Rasterizer Thread 1** that is constantly **Rasterizing Paint**:

[image]

**1.** What's actually happening in this Rasterizer Thread?

**2.** Could it be the cause of low performance?

Comment: Could be a plugin. You can also check the actual rendered frames

Comment: I've used `npx create-react-app` to initialize the app, and my `package.json` is as clean as possible - only react scripts included, no plugins added

Comment: I meant chrome plugins. Try to see if a non-react app does the same just to be sure

Comment: I disabled all chrome extensions and still the same effect - constant paint rasterization